# Golden Section Search

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization

I've been asked the following question: The golden section method is to be applied to a unimodal function to find the minimum in the domain $[0,2]$. Given we require the error not be greater than $\epsilon=0.005$ how many iterations do we need to perform? I've been told to assume $r_k=0.382$ as the symmetric interval subdivision.

Is there something I'm missing here? How am I meant to calculate the error without being supplied a function? Perhaps it is something about the function being unimodal but I'm lost any hints appreciated. Does the fact it's unimodal mean I don't actually need the functional value to assess my next range of values?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "the a unimodal function"...

Comment: It was a typo I've edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Check the algorithm. The golden section search reduces the interval known to contain the minimum by a fixed factor each iteration. You don't need the function to answer.

Comment: I think I'm right in saying given $[a,b]$ I can evaluate $[a_1,b_1]$ where $a_1=a+r(b-a)$ and $b_1=a+(1-r)(b-a)$ and take $b_1$ as part of the new interval $[a,b_1]$ hence evaluating everything to the left of $b_1$ (because we are searching for a minimum so it will have to be less than the maximum interval) and proceed in an iterative fashion until the required tolerance is reached between $[a_n,b_n]$?

Comment: Worked it out, thanks for your hint. You just take the maximum interval length at each iteration which happens to be $b_1$ described in the above comment, then just iterate this repeatedly until you reach the desired tolerance. It was easier for me to conceptualize it graphically once I did this I had it.